# How to make a patch request with Kivy UrlRequest

Tags: python, kivy

How to make a patch request to the web with Kivy's UrlRequest?

Comment: *who knows how to make...* probably alot of people, to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [kivy docs for urlRequest](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html)

```
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
req = UrlRequest(url, on_success, on_redirect, on_failure, on_error,
                 on_progress, req_body, req_headers, chunk_size,
                 timeout, method, decode, debug, file_path, ca_file,
                 verify)
```

Use patch as your parameter for `method`